# Laravel Unable to download files in csv format

Tags: php, laravel-5

I get the issue in my code
What I want: after clicking on the export button, one CSVfile would be automatic download from the browser.

but it only displays the data in network tab in inspect element but not downloading.

```
public function Exportcsv(Request $recuestdata) {

 $headers = array(
    "Content-type" => "text/csv",
    "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=file.csv",
    "Pragma" => "no-cache",
    "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    "Expires" => "0"
  );

  $filename = "order";
  $output = fopen($filename, 'w+');
  $data=json_decode($recuestdata['row']);

  foreach ($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($output, $line);
  }
  return Response::download($filename, 'order.csv', $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

```
$filename = "order";
```

to

```
$filename = "order.csv";
```

also the download method in Laravel 5 can be used as

```
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

however what you have used is applicable in both Laravel 4 and 5 but change `$filename` to `$output`

```
return Response::download($output, 'order.csv', $headers);
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the value of $pathToFile variable